# Coda2: How to select select variables

Tags: coda

I'm new to Coda2, and I have a question.
How to select a variable with double-click like in sublimetext2 (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ja85n.png)

Is there a keyboard shortcut that will let me select all of the variable in Coda2 like in sublimetext2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest thing to that is the find dialog box. Double click the variable name, copy it, type shift+command+F, and then paste it in the search field you can search for it with the Open Files filter selected and it will highlight each line that the variable is on.